# Module not showing up in Magento Admin panel

Tags: magento, magento2.2

I have created a simple "hello world" module in Magento(2.2.1) and seems to be working fine. http://35.224.126.44/magento/helloworld/index/test

But I am not able to find the installed module in the admin panel.
Please let me know how to check installed modules through admin panel. As I don't see an "Advance" option inside store > configuration > Advance >?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Magento version 2.2 on, the Advanced Menu is not available.

Though you can manually check/enable/disable modules from `app/etc/config.php` file or can use following commands:

- To disable: `php bin/magento module:disable -c -f [CompanyName]_[ModuleName]`
- To enable: `php bin/magento module:enable -c -f [CompanyName]_[ModuleName]`